# how to run 1000+users using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Please explain the procedure to run JMeter for 1000+ users  using 2 systems  with 8GB configuration JMeter server and application server.
But while running 100 users with 4GB configuration application which is used in other system became slow then will the application supports for 1000 users using 2 or more systems?

Comment: Sowmya, it looks like you have two different questions here: how to configure JMeter to run for 1000+ users; and what the impact of running that many users will be on your application since it became slow with a 100 user test. Please ask these separately - you will get better answers that way. Also, take a look at the Help Center, particularly How to ask a Good Question (http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).